# org-babel-execute:sql: receiving errors and no returns

Tags: org-babel, sql

```
#+name: Part 1 Task 1
#+header: :engine mysql
#+header: :dbhost localhost
#+header: :dbuser subject
#+header: :dbpassword 1234
#+header: :database hmsec
#+begin_src sql
  SELECT sensorId, type, location 
  FROM sensor
  ORDER BY location 
#+end_src
```

`org-babel-execute:sql: Wrong type argument: sequencep, 1234`
If i removed the password on the server and the password line i get:
`org-babel-insert-result: Wrong type argument: markerp, nil`

used to guide here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html

Running the query on the server gives 5 rows.

Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: For the first error, it looks like Emacs reads `1234` as a number, so try to put `"1234"` instead.  For the second, try and get a backtrace by enabling the debugger (with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`) before (re)triggering the error

Comment: chainging the password worked. Strange that it did not work with removeing the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first error, it looks like Emacs reads `1234` as a number, so try to put `"1234"` instead.

For the second, try and get a backtrace by enabling the debugger (with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`) before (re)triggering the error.

[ Given the second error, I didn't expect that fixing the password would work.  But apparently, my comment was actually an answer, so here it is.  ]